# Check if email exists in user list using AngularFire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to check if there exists a user that have email = someemail@gmai.com in the Firebase database.

I use this function and is download 50MB of data in my PC after 10 minute I get a response that exists. There is any way that I can get that less than 5 second I don't want to wait 10 minute.

in PHP is like the

```
SELECT FROM ALL USERS WERE EMAIL = 'george@gmail.com'
```

This is the database:

```
"users" : {

    user: {
      "email" : "george@gmail.com",
      "custom_id" : 534253,
      "description" : "some small description"
    },

    1754: {
      "email" : "natassa@gmail.com", <---- i want to find if this email from 5000 users exist in database and if exist i want to return true
      "custom_id" : 110571,   
      "description" : "some small description"
    },

    1755: {
      "email" : "george@gmail.com",
      "custom_id" : dsgfsdfds,
      "description" : "some small description"
    },

  }
```

This function give me response after 10 min:

```
check_if_email_exist(email: string) {

    this.users = this.db.list('/user', { query: {
      orderByChild: 'email',
      equalTo: x,
      limitToLast: 10,
    }} ) as FirebaseListObservable<Product[]>;

    console.log(this.users);

    return this.users;
}
```

Comment: You're passing `x` into `equalTo`, which should probably be `equalTo: email`. But if `x` is the value to filter on, that performance seems pretty unusual. Did you add an index to `email`? If not, there will be a warning shown in the JavaScript console. If that is not the problem, is there any way you can set up a jsbin that reproduces this performance for you?

Comment: Frank, I am the George hatouts this is my second account. Yes inside x I pass email that I take from input I want to check before I submit a form if the email exist in database and if the email exist I want to notify the user, that email exist

Comment: I gona give you an example that is not the answer for my problem but describe the problem give me 2 min

Comment: Frank many many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I find the problem thanx to https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen is say something about **index** and when I look in my chrome console I find warning that says something about index and when I look in the database rules I understand what is missing

### I add this inside database rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",

    "needs": {
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      ".indexOn": "name"
    },

    "brands": {
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      ".indexOn": "name"
    },

    "products": {
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      ".indexOn": "custom_id"   <========== This line you want 
    }

  }
}
```